# Is it possible to upload multiple images in a joomla field?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Joomla has fields which can be added to articles. For example a datepicker and an image field. The problem is I can only add one image, is there a possibility to add multiple images?

The best would be if it is stored in json format to the database.

I am using joomla 3.9

In the past there was a gallery field but they have removed that in newer versions of Joomla.

Comment: Please ask your Joomla question at Joomla Stack Exchange so that the Joomla support audience doesn't have to patrol both Joomla Stack Exchange and StackOverflow to offer help.

Answer (score 0):

You use the **List of Images** or **Media** custom field in Joomla for that. The List of images field provides you a field with a dropdown list of images in a particular folder (which you setup when you create this custom field). The Media field provides you image upload possibilities.

**For custom fields** in an article

> Click **Content  →  Article** in the Admin Control Panel
>
> Click Fields in the menu on the left side
>
> Click the button New in tool bar on the top

[image]

And you just created a new field.

It is also important that in order to see the custom fields in your article editor, you have to show article options slider in the Backend article edit view for showing the custom field tabs. **So activate Show Article Options.** You can set this in **Global Configuration->articles** (from the left side menu items).

[image]

I hope this is what you were looking for.

**UPDATE**

I'm sorry I just realized that you need upload capability of the field. Then you have to create a **Media** custom field with the same method as described above. It has multifile upload capabilities and as far as I know, the images is in **json format** in the db.

UPDATE - GALLERY MANAGEMENT

Since the question got a bit cleared by the OP in the comments finally and it came out that the question is how to upload and INSERT multiple images in an article, then my suggestion is for you not to invent the wheel regarding Joomla, try to use Phoca Gallery component and plugins which is great free extension package for Joomla and I think it can serve your purpose quite well:

https://www.phoca.cz/phocagallery

Comment: That is not possible with the media field. I can only add one image, if I select two and click insert there still is only one image.

Comment: @twan - ohh, I got you, I’ll check that issue and will update my answer on this.

Comment: @twan - I checked the media field in my Joomla and it is absolutely possible to upload multiple images with media field so I do not really understand your issue with that. Media field is using Joomla media manager and it is absolutely capable of multi file upload.

Comment: @twan - if you are talking about insert multiple images, that is another word in english.

Comment: @twan  Then I'll write that in my update of my answer, now that is clear what you are up to :)

Comment: Before you give effort for an updated answer, I don't mean inside the textbox. I know how you can add multiple images like that already. I need them to be saved seperately from the introtext/fulltext, best would be in JSON format. So really in a field not multiple images alongside text of the article.

Comment: @twan - Then you should still clear a bit more your question about where do you want to use those images for? The field which lets you upload images would be in the article body itself? Then the uploaded images would appear somewhere or not? Or the uploaded images should be just saved into a folder and the paths of the images would be saved in a database table where you will get them back from. What you want is unclear and gets a bit complicated...

Comment: A Joomla field is an HTML input field. All of them.

Comment: I am using the joomla database and backend without a joomla frontend (frontend is custom). I am trying to create a gallery on this custom frontend, so the intro image will not work since there is space for 1 image, and adding multiple fields is no option because every article has a different amount of images in the gallery I am trying to create. 

What I am looking for is a field where I can add multiple images so that I can get those images from my database, linked with id to an article and loop the result on my frontend page from the JSON object.

Comment: @twan - I do not want to put much effort in this question, since I do not see a really valid purpose for that. However I updated my answer with an alternative solution to your purpose.